# How to set a dynamic data path for saving a CSV Data in Python without using Pandas

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to figure out how to code that my program opens a window so that I can set the path where the csv file should be saved. At the moment the file is saved where my .py data is located.
So how can I set a "dynamic" data path only using "import csv"?

This is my code:

```
import csv

fruit = ('apple','banana','peach')
eater = ('Timothy', 'James', 'Michael')
list = []
for i in range(len(fruit)):
    var1 = fruit[i]
    var2 = eater[i]
    smalllist = (var1, var2)
    list.append(smalllist)


with open('eatingfruit.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    thewriter = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    thewriter.writerow(['fruit', 'eater'])
    for i in list:
        thewriter.writerow(i)
```

Edit: When you run the code there should be opened the explorer window where the user can set the data path where the data should be saved
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Do you mean you want to ask the user to input a path? In that case you can let the user type it in the console or you have to use a GUI framework to create a graphical interface where the user can input the path. In that case you should look at tkinter https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/. But this will require importing tkinter.

Comment: you can specify the any path in your script like `with open('C:\Users\path\eatingfruit.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:'`. where exactly do you want it saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have manual input for both file path and filename.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

filepath = input("enter file path: ")
file = input("enter file name: ")

df = pd.read_csv(f'{filepath}{filepath}/')
```